# How to delete all associations in a Hibernate JoinTable at once?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, join

We have the following two entities with many-to-many association:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable( name = "user_has_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "role_fk" ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "user_fk" ) } )
  private Set<User>           userCollection; 
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class User {
  ...
  //bi-directional many-to-many association to Role
  @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "userCollection" )
  private Set<Role>        roleCollection;
  ...
}
```

If we want to truncate all data with

```
em.createQuery( "DELETE Role" ).executeUpdate();
```

we have to clear all associations in the "user_has_role" JoinTable like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299455/hibernate-manytomany-delete-relation-problem):

```
for ( ... )
{
    A a = aDao.getObject(aId);
    B b = bDao.getObject(bId);

    b.getAs().remove(a);
    a.getBs().remove(b);
    bDao.saveObject(b); 
}
```

Is there a way to do delete all associations in the JoinTable at once without iterating over all the data? 
Maybe there is a special HQL-Command like `DELETE Role.user_has_role` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the JPA spec clearly writes that bulk operations are not cascaded to **related entities** (section 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations), I expect providers to deal at least with join tables. Sadly, Hibernate doesn't and this is logged in [HHH-1917](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1917). Workaround: use native SQL.