# hibernate ignoring the cascade attribute

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations, cascade

i'm using hibernate annotations in my project, I've created the tables and it's all good except that when i check the database their's no cascade even tho I've made sure to put it in the classes.
here is an exemple of how i do it :

```
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8271695210797279161L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "IDitem", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int iditem;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDDIVISION", nullable = false)
private Division division;
@Column(name = "SIGLE", length = 254)
private String sigleItem;
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 254)
private String description;
....
}
```

i have cascade = CascadeType.ALL in all the ManyToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany cases.
i tried also to add

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)

like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299455/hibernate-manytomany-delete-relation-problem) but nothing changed

can you help me solve the problem? thank you!

Comment: Hi, what database you are using? is it MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Maybe you forget to add the child to the set of the parent.

```java
division.getItems().add(item); // <-- That was my mistake.
item.setDivision(division);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't use the correct database engine. 
You should specify hibernate dialect as: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect instead of MySQLDialect. Otherwise, it will be default to MyISAM, which doesn't support relation.

Comment: i changed it but it stated to give errors like    août 10, 2012 2:36:47 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
Avertissement: Unknown table 'participants_audit'
août 10, 2012 2:36:47 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
Avertissement: SQL Warning: 1051, SQLState: 42S02
août 10, 2012 2:36:47 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
Avertissement: Unknown table 'quest_ecarts'                                        ...

Comment: Do you have Entity and Table annotation for the class. Like @Table(name = 'participants_audit'). Otherwise, does it error only happen after you change the Hibernate Dialect ?

Comment: yes it only happens when i change to MySQLInnoDBDialect and yes i have in each class the anotation                                          @Entity
@Table(name = "name")

Comment: Could you manually change your database engine to InnoDB to see if this error still occur ?

Comment: chenged it to inoobd but tables are still not created, i get:                                                     ...
Avertissement: SQL Warning: 1051, SQLState: 42S02
août 10, 2012 6:07:23 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
Avertissement: Unknown table 'division'

Comment: and  ...                                                                                   Grave: Unsuccessful: create table question (idQuestion integer not null auto_increment unique, text varchar(254), commentaire varchar(254), them_id integer, primary key (idQuestion)) type=InnoDB
août 10, 2012 6:07:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport create

Comment: So you don't even have the table created? Have you set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to update. It will maintain your schema to be consistent with your model .

Comment: no the tables are not created when i change MySQLInnoDBDialect, for the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto i set it to create (created a new database)

Comment: In the question you say the tables exist.  Now you're saying they don't. It is impossible to help when you provide misleading information. -1 on the question.

Comment: i said i already created the tables but their is no cascad, then Khue Vu suggested that i change the database engine and try again so offcorse i'm going to try and create tables all over again with his suggestion and that's when i said that it didn't work (changing the engine wouldn't let me even create the tables), hope it's cleared out