# How to delete a ManyToMany item using JPQL?

Tags: java, many-to-many, jpql

I have two models, say :

```
BlogPost(title, message)
Tags(name)
```

Both have a ManyToMany relationship defined.

Using JPQL, I delete a list of `BlogPost` with this query:

```
DELETE FROM BlogPost b WHERE b IN :list
```

(:list is a List from a previous SELECT requet).

Doing so, I have a **ConstraintViolationException** because of the relation between `BlogPost` and `Tags`.

Is there a way to delete the relation without deleting the Tags using JPQL?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself with the solution I came up. I'm not sure it's the best one, but at least, it works.

Since you want to bulk delete something that have a ManyToMany related items, you first have to delete the relation (in the join table), or do a loop and for each item, delete manually (insane and too much heavy).

So, since JPQL does not allow to do it, a possible way is to make a **native SQL query** for deleting the id you want in the related table, and then, do the bulk delete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the association first, before you delete the entity.

Comment: And how can I do that using jpql?

Comment: You don't do this with JPQL. You do this by manipulating the entity objects. If they are in attached and mainpulated in the same transaction, then it should be fine.

Comment: Could you show me how to manipulate the entity objects? What I want to do is delete many BlogPost without having to do a loop and calling `->delete()` for each entry. Just doing it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

JPA create a table BlogPost_Tags which stores ID of BlogPost and Tags.

So when you try to delete a BlogPost, the constraint on the BlogPost_Tags failed.

You need to delete the relation before delete the Post, and there is no easy way in JPQL, you have to use the EntityManager.