# hibernate - delete from many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following two POJOs:

```
@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer identifier;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Member> members = new HashSet<Member>();

    // --- constructors ---

    public Project() {
    }

    // --- getters ---

    public Integer getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public Set<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "member")
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {
    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer identifier;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members")
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<Project>();

    // --- constructors ---

    public Member() {
    }

    // --- getters ---

    public Integer getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }
}
```

What is common practise do delete from a many-to-many relation? The following code works perfectly, but it generates a lot of overhead. First, there are some queries:

1. 1 query to get the projects, triggered by `member.getProjects()`
2. N queries to get all members of the each project, triggered by `project.getMembers()`

Second, the complete data set of the project (query 1) and member (query 2) is fetched, and not only the identifier.

```
final Member member = ...;
for (final Project project : member.getProjects()) {
    project.getMembers().remove(member);
}
db.delete(member);
```

Is it possible to do this more efficient without being forced to write ad-hoc queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

[How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join)

Additionally you have the option to use jpql statements to delete data:

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_query_delete

But I think the first link is what you are looking for.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the first link proposes what I am doing here. However, my concern is that it generated a lot of query/data overhead.

Comment: Well you'r right that will produce some overhead, but as far as I know this is the common way. 
However, did you try out the jpql solution? That should work with very few Statements.