# cascade delete with ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities. I want to be able to delete a User and any entry in the UserGroupMap that contains that User should also get deleted. However everytime I try deleting a user that also has a entry in UserGroupMap I am getting the following error.*Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails* How can I achieve this behavior?

```
@Entity
public class User {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.All)
   private Set<Group> groups;

 }


@Entity
public class Group {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column
   private String type;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "UserGroupMap", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id") )
   private Set<User> users;

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1082095/5516322

Answer (score 0):

You should add (cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) to your many to many relationship

like this example

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

Comment: there is no orphanRemoval for ManyToMany

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand looking at the entities, `Group` should not be deleted and the `User` belongs to a `Group`.

This means the `Group` entity is the parent side.
When removing the `User` you need to remove it from the `Group` side.

Create a method on the `Group` entity called "remove" which takes a `User` parameter which is the user you want to remove.

```
public void remove(User user) {

    for(Iterator<User> iterator = users.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        User removeUser = iterator.next();
        /*
         * you can check here if the user is equal to the parameter user
         * if equal remove
         */
        if(removeUser.equal(user)) {
           removeUser.setGroup(null);
           iterator.remove();
        {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity
public class User {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.All, orphanRemoval=true)
   private Set<Group> groups;

 }
```

orphanRemoval option should handle the deletion of the childs

Comment: there is no orphanRemoval for ManyToMany

Comment: If you are using hibernate then @OnDelete action would be useful to you.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/OnDelete.html  @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

Comment: like @kittels said there is no orphanRemoval in manytomany since hibernate would have to check if each record has a relation in the other table, which is not possible.