# Propagate cascade delete raises foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I'm using Spring Boot (2.1.0.RELEASE) with Spring Data JPA. Database is MySQL.

I have some problem to chain cascade delete.

I have the following model :

[image: Database model]

I do not use `@ManyToMany` because I need additional fields in generated tables, so my entities are as follow (useless properties have been removed) :

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
public class Request {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Resource resource;

}


@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource")
public class Resource {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "resource")
    private Set<ResourceArticle> resourceArticles;

}

@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource_article")
public class ResourceArticle {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
    private Article article;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id")
    private Resource resource;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "resourceArticle")
    private Set<ResourceArticleOption> options;

}

@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource_article_option")
public class ResourceArticleOption {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
    private Option option;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_article_id")
    private ResourceArticle resourceArticle;

}
```

Then from my manager I simply issue the request `delete` extending `CrudRepository` :

```
/* Repositroy */
public interface RequestRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, Long> {
}

/* Manager */
@Transactional
@Component("requestMgr")
public class RequestManager {

    @Autowired
    RequestRepository requestRepository;

    public void delete(Request request) {
        requestRepository.delete(request);
    }

}

/* Viewmodel */
public class RequestVm {

    @WireVariable
    private RequestManager requestMgr;

    public void deleteRequest(Request req) {
        requestMgr.delete(req);
    }

}
```

Error is :

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot delete or update a parent
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`my_db`.`resource_article`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK5wqvprkwx05fb5hgt6w9h7nbk` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_id`) REFERENCES
>   `resource` (`id`))

The output when enabling tracing :

```
delete from request where id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [24]
delete from resource where id=?
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [71]
SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
(conn=30) Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`resource_article`, CONSTRAINT `FK5wqvprkwx05fb5hgt6w9h7nbk` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_id`) REFERENCES `resource` (`id`))
```

Strange that it tries to delete in the order `request` > `resource` > `resource_article` > `resource_article_option` ?

I *need* `CascadeType.ALL` as I want to PERSIST and DELETE.

I can break the chain by setting reference to `null` before deleting but of course it results in orphan records in the database.

What is the best strategy here ?

Comment: Note that you can cascade multiple operations without cascading *all* operations.  That doesn't necessarily mean that you don't need or want `CascadeType.ALL`, or that using it is causing your problem, just that the reason you give for using it is not valid (JPA recognizes more operations than just `PERSIST` and `REMOVE`).

Comment: As far as I know or can tell, deleting a `Resource` *via* a repository extending `CrudRepository` should honor the JPA cascading properties declared for the parent entity.  That that does not appear to be happening leads me to suspect that something is not as you present it, or else that something important has been omitted.  Perhaps the deployed versions of your entities do not have cascading enabled?  Perhaps you've customized your repository such that its `delete()` method somehow bypasses JPA?

Comment: Thanks John. Indeed I misspoke, I know I can use multiple cascade types, but as I understand I have no reason not to cascade everything so I use `ALL`. Other properties I have not presented here are basic `@Column` and should not cause any problem. The only thing that I have voluntary omitted is that I have another table on top of this, a `REQUEST` table which have a 1-1 relation to `RESOURCE`, the delete is done on this request. Finally note that I use Envers for auditing, my entities have `@Audited` annotation, so for each table I got another `xxx_audit_log` table. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by removing in each relationship the entity that is not the owner of the relationship.

Cascade remove in `@ManyToMany` relationships is not only applied to the link table but to the other side of the relationship as well.

It is a well-known problem when deleting from `@ManyToMany` associations (this is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join) for example), but I did not pay attention because my annotations are not direct `@ManyToMany` but double `@OneToMany` associations, and I though JPA would cascade delete like in simple `@OneToMany` relationships but it seems I was wrong.

I have used `@preRemove` to clean the relation before deleting the request :

In `ResourceArticle` :

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    article.getResourceArticles().remove(this);
}
```

In `ResourceArticleOption` :

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    option.getResourceArticleOptions().remove(this);
}
```

Then all is working perfectly.