# Foreign key constraint @ManyToMany relationship preventing deletion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I've three associated records (`Conference`, `SubmissionRecord`, `SubmissionAuthorRecord`). Every `SubmissionRecord` has a `Conference` object and has a `List<SubmissionAuthorRecord>`.

When I delete a Conference record if the SubmissionRecord is associated with that Conference, it should cascade and delete as well. However, I keep getting a `` java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`viz`.`submission_record_author_set`, CONSTRAINT `FKgnqq52l26bitkmojk1oiuaki1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`submission_record_s_id`) REFERENCES `submission_record` (`s_id`)) `` error message.

The table `submission_record_author_set` is create automatically and I have no entity that maps to it.

I understand the issue lies in the fact that the `submission_record_author_set` rows are preventing the `SubmissionRecord` from being deleted and have tried the @PreRemove method described here ([How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join)) but to no avail. Maybe there's an issue with the ManyToMany annotation? Cause I do not see the equivalent annotation in the SubmissionAuthorRecord either.

```
@Entity
public class SubmissionRecord {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity", strategy = "xyz")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "s_id")
    private Long id;

    @Exportable(name = "Submission Id", nameInDB = "s_submission_id")
    @Column(name = "s_submission_id")
    private String submissionId;

    // internal set of authors of the associated
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<SubmissionAuthorRecord> authorSet;

    @JoinColumn(name="conference_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Conference conference;

    //...
}

@Entity
public class Conference {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity", strategy = "xyz")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private Long id;

    private String creatorIdentifier;

    private String conferenceName;

    private String conferenceYear;
}

@Entity
public class SubmissionAuthorRecord {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity", strategy = "xyz")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "s_author_id")
    private Long id;

    private String dataSet;

    @Column(name = "s_author_name")
    private String name;
}
```

The `submission_author_record_set` table looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: did you try to add "cascade=true" ?

Comment: @rmalchow you mean the annotation? Yep I have!