# Many to Many Spring Jpa Delete does not work

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

I am new with Spring jpa and I am trying to perform the deletion operation on spring jpa many to many database. My database has user and drug. I can delete an user and deletes also the rows associated to it from user_drug table, I can delete a drug that has no linking to the user_drug table, but i cannot delete a drug that is also in the user_drug table.
I had a look on this page but the solutions from there do not work for me.. [How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join)

Here is my code for User entity:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "user_drug",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "drug_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
 private Set<Drug> drugs = new HashSet<>();
```

Here is the code for Drug entity:

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "drugs",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

And here is the delet method from DrugServiceImpl:

```
public void delete(Drug drug)
{
    drug.getUsers().clear();
    drugRepository.delete(drug);
}
```

I have also printed the size of drug.getUsers() after clear operation and it is 0. Why isn't it delete the drug from database?
I've tried in many ways.. Can someone please send some help?

Comment: Create a transaction that deletes it from both sides?

Comment: If i want to delete a drug I want it to be deleted from user_drug and from drug. But the users that bought that drug should not be deleted from the user database

Comment: I mean remove the drug's reference from the user, and then (in a transaction) save the user's state and delete the drug from the DB.

Comment: Excellent! I did it, now it works. Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

that is how the cascade works it deletes from the relation table only and in the `ManyToMany` the relation table here is the `user_drug` table

and for this cases there are many solution one of them is deleting the `drug` in the same transaction of the deleting `user`

but another solution that will save the effort that you create the `ManyToMany` table as entity and put cascade on the `drug` object in the relation table

like this

But this in the `User` entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="user")
private Set<UserDrug> drugs = new HashSet<>();
```

the `UserDrug` entity

```
public class UserDrug {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="drug_id")
    Drug drug;

 }
```