# Spring boot mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, relationship, entity-relationship

I'm trying to map User and Script, my main goal is that a user can create many script and own many scripts
but Script can be created only by one user and be owned by many

```
public class Script {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;
@NotBlank(message = "Script name cannot be empty")
@Column(unique = true)
private String scriptName;
private boolean enabled;
@ManyToOne
private User author;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ownedScripts")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

public class User {
@Id
@Column(updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;
@NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be empty")
@Column(unique = true)
private String discordUsername;
@NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be empty")
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
private Role role;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Script> ownedScripts = new ArrayList<>();
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Script> createdScripts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: According to your requirements, what should happen if you delete a user ? do you expect all of its created scripts to be deleted ? do you want all of its owned scripts to be deleted ? . You simply can't put CascadeType.ALL like that. Please be clear in your question.

Comment: Once I delete a user I want his crated scripts to be left in the DB and the user+owned scripts to be removed @crazy_code

Comment: 1. When user is deleted then the created scripts shouldn't be deleted for this you have to remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the User entity. (Note : By default no operations are cascaded). With this when you delete user then scripts won't be deleted
2. To delete in a many to many relationship refer this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, so I have removed the cascade from User, I understand the way to delete in MTM will implement it