# ERROR: update or delete on table "courses" violates foreign key constraint "fk998yb1badftsiklfh13bcw3ol" on table "teacher_courses"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, in a model of five entities and when I run my code there are no errors. However, whenever I make delete all request from insomnia, I get the error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "courses" violates foreign key constraint "fk998yb1badftsiklfh13bcw3ol" on table "teacher_courses"
Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "teacher_courses".

I understand that there is something wrong with the cascading between the two items, but I do not know how to resolve the issues.

```
package com.example.springapiwithsecuritydevelopment.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@Getter @Setter
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String courseName;

    @Column
    private LocalDate courseStartDate;

    @Column
    private LocalDate courseEndDate;

    // One course to many lessons
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("course")
    private List<Lesson> lessonList;

    // Many courses to many Students
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courseList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("courseList")
    private List<Student> studentList;

    // Subject to course
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("courseList")
    private Subject subject;

    // ManyCourses to Many Teachers
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "courseList", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("courseList")
    private List<Teacher> teacherList;

    // Adding constructors
    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String courseName, LocalDate courseStartDate, LocalDate courseEndDate) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseStartDate = courseStartDate;
        this.courseEndDate = courseEndDate;
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.springapiwithsecuritydevelopment.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String secondName;

    @Column(nullable = false) @NotNull
    private LocalDate birthday;

    @Column
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "teacher_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("teacherList")
    private List<Course> courseList;


    // Adding constructors
    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(String firstName, String secondName, LocalDate birthday, Integer age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend found a solution that works through this, [How to remove entity with ManyToMany relationship in JPA (and corresponding join table rows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082095/how-to-remove-entity-with-manytomany-relationship-in-jpa-and-corresponding-join).

In the end, I just put

```
  @PreRemove
    private void removeCoursesFromTeacher() {
        for (Teacher t : teacherList) {
            t.getCourseList().remove(this);
        }
    }
```

On the none owning side of the relationship.

Answer (score -1):

can you try to change the cascade type for Teacher class to

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just throws an error for me, Failed to execute CommandLineRunner detached entity passed to persist.

Comment: try to change CascadeType.DETACH to CascadeType.PERSIST for all the mappings

Comment: I put a solution link above, in case you are interested!

Comment: ps, I am also trying your suggested solutions also!